# is the statement "for any person x" and "for a person x who can be anyone " same?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

After the logic class, I am thinking about the statements interpret that :
is the statement `"for any person x"` and `"for a person x who can be anyone "` same?

Comment: I think they are the same.

Comment: @user41728 Yes! I think so, but ... I not fairly sure, so I am here to ask for some confirmation

Comment: I think I could see them not being the same though.  You could say that some statement like, "X is taking a math class", is not true "for any person x", meaning that it's not true for all of them.  But it is true for a person x, who can be anyone, meaning that it is at least true for 1 person, who can be anyone, but we just don't know which one he is.

Comment: Consider the following two statements: "For any person x, the age of x is 42" vs. "For a person x who can be anyone, the age of x is 42." If you're looking at a large enough population, one of these statements is probably true, and the other one is probably not.

Comment: so guys, most of you think they are not same, So I can only interpret `∀ x` to  for any person x, right?

Comment: I think those statements are the same.  Person x who is 42 can not be anyone unless for anyone the age is 42.

Comment: The second sentence is kind of ambiguous, the ambiguity comes from the word "can be". If it means "might be" then the two are different, if it means "are able to be" then the two are the same.

Comment: Try to avoid ambiguous phrases like "person x who can be anyone." Logic is all about making inferences. If you want to infer something about all people, you can start with the unambiguous premise: Let x be a person. If you can infer that P(x) is then true, then you can generalize: For all x, if x is a person, then P(x). Here, the P(x) is assumed to contain only one free variable, namely x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not statements, they are quantifiers.   However, they are the same quantifier: the universal quantifier, in the domain of persons.

> 'for any person $x$', 'for an arbitrary person $x$', 'for a person $x$ who is arbitrary', 'for any one $x$ who is a person', 'for $x$, a person who can be anyone'...

The phrase can be expressed many ways in natural language.   It is however, highly preferable to engage in the least verbose pontification required to express the concept with maximum clarity — er, I mean,— It is better to be efficient and clear.

Thus "for any person $x$" does the job.